# Android - Kill camera process in the background

Tags: android, kotlin, android-camera, background-process, kill-process

Nowadays how does it work to kill the camera process in the background?

I tried a couple of solutions:

```
val pid = Process.getUidForName("camera")
Process.killProcess(pid)

or

activityManager.killBackgroundProcesses("com.android.camera");
```

I'm also using the kill background process permission in my Manifest: `android.permission.KILL_BACKGROUND_PROCESSES`

I also tried to figure out how I could get all the background processes running with `activityManger.runningAppProcesses` but this code only return an array with my current active app, I can't see the camera or anything else.

Although with the `PackageManager` I managed to get all app installed on the phone and check if they are flagged has "stopped" or not so I can filter which one is running or not. But still the `Process.killprocess` is not working. I guess I'm missing some permissions to make it work.

Comment: I'm rather glad applications don't have direct access over other applications like this unless they are either root or system app.

Comment: Please don't make more work for other people by vandalizing your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the [CC BY-SA 4.0 license](//creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/), for Stack Exchange to distribute that content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By Stack Exchange policy, the non-vandalized version of the post is the one which is distributed. Thus, any vandalism will be reverted. If you want to know more about deleting a post please see: [How does deleting work?](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not do it with the regular app, and one thing you can do it try implementing the device manager.
you can use [DeviceAdministration class](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/admin/device-admin.html) to **control the camera source**(block and unblock). 
Check out this [Github repo](https://github.com/barneyElDinosaurio/LockCamera) with an example.